# Passing msg data from Python to C++

Tags: ros, python, c++, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have a topic written in Python, inside that workspace I have two message files:

Msg1

```
Header header
geometry_msgs/Vector3 direction
geometry_msgs/Vector3 normal
geometry_msgs/Point palmpos
geometry_msgs/Vector3 ypr
```

Msg2

Header header

```
float64[3] hand_direction
float64[3] hand_normal
float64[3] hand_palm_pos
float64 hand_pitch
float64 hand_roll
float64 hand_yaw
```

If I therefore do: `std_msgs/Header header` I get the information. The problem being is that now I'm using C++ to write another topic to subscribe to this. I don't know what to put inside of the `callback` function, for example:

```
void callback(const [here]& msg)
{

}
```

Since when I'm using the `Point2Cloud` I can use the following:

```
void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2Ptr& msg)
{
    // Blah
}
```

COuld anyone please tell me what I should therefore use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112121/passing-msg-data-from-python-to-c++/) by [Phorce](https://answers.ros.org/users/9496/phorce/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2013-12-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2013-12-19**:
Have you tried your_package::Msg1Ptr?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-20**:
Why do you have two different messages that seem to contain the same data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If messages are defined in the package `my_package`, then you would use

```
void callback(const my_package::Msg1ConstPtr& msg)
```

and ensure that you have a

```
#include <my_package/Msg1.h>
```

at the beginning.

Those look like the leap_motion messages; to use those include "leap_motion/leap.h" and "leap_motion/leapros.h" and the use `leap_motion::leapConstPtr` or `leap_motion::leaprosConstPtr`.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2013-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2016-10-28**:
I know that using a *Nodelet* would be more memory efficient, but it's not supported for nodes written in Python. Do you believe to that writing the point cloud data to disk (as a binary file) and just passing a simple message flag for the receiver node to read such a file is any better (speed/mem)?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2016-10-31**:
Is this related to the above question or my answer? I guess you should open a new question. My answer to you: You will probably have to measure it to find out which is more efficient. But I would first make sure that this is actually a bottleneck for you...